# Install latest stable version of MonoDevelop

Tags: .net, linux, mono, monodevelop, flatpak

I've followed the [official instructions](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux) to install MonoDevelop using Flatpak. However, installed version of MonoDevelop is 7.1 **Preview** (build 1291).

How can I install latest stable version (6.1 Service Release 1 (6.1.2.44)) instead of the preview?

Comment: 7.x is considered stable, while 6.x is obsolete.

Comment: maybe there's a git tag or branch for it?